# Excel date to Mysql Date

Tags: mysql, excel, date, date-format

Sir, I am importing excel sheet into MySql database,  One cell contains Date  in format as shown  2013-12-30  (YYYY-MM-DD). On Importing , I am getting Value of Date as numeric 40248.0 because Date  format is showing as 2013-12-30 but double clicking on cell shows as 30/12/2013. Kindly resolve . Thanks

```
                              if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
                {
                    System.out.println(" The rowvalue is Numeric so Moving ahead");
                    String str = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    System.out.println(" String ---->"+str);
                    list1.add(str);

                }


                   ....
                    // some more code





              String failure_date= list.get(5).toString();

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date failure_date1= null;
            String new_date = null;
            try{failure_date1   =(Date)df.parse(failure_date);
            new_date=df.format(failure_date1);
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

            System.out.println(" The failure_date is "+ new_date);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ' in the date cell and then type your date value to keep the same format of what you type and disable the excel's auto formatting.